# How to encrypt entire linux sda?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, encryption, diskcryptor

I know a little bit about encrypting partition with "cryptsetup", but it cannot encrypt live drive like /dev/sda1 for "/" or root partition ...

is there any tutorial out there for encrypting entire linux hard drive and ask/prompt for password message when booting ?

```
root@DATO-SERVER:/usr/local/src/.cache# lsblk -i -o NAME,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME   TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    disk
|-sda1 part /data/works
`-sda2 part /data/life
sdb    disk
`-sdb1 part /data/backups
sdc    disk
|-sdc1 part /boot
`-sdc2 part /data/sdcard
sdd    disk
|-sdd1 part /
|-sdd2 part /data/osx
|-sdd3 part /home
`-sdd4 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any tutorial out there for encrypting entire linux hard drive and ask/prompt for password message when booting ?

Note that configuring a password prompt on boot for `/`  **depends on the distribution.** That is, Ubuntu has one method and its own instructions, Arch Linux has another, Gentoo has yet another. It also depends on your bootloader and firmware – for example, GRUB can decrypt a LUKS-encrypted `/` entirely on its own, but Syslinux cannot and would require a `/boot` partition.

- Search keywords: "*<distro name>* encrypted root"
- Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto
- Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system
- Gentoo: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Full_Disk_Encryption_From_Scratch_Simplified

(In contrast, configuring cryptsetup for data partitions is done nearly the same way everywhere.)

> I know a little bit about encrypting partition with "cryptsetup", but it cannot encrypt live drive like /dev/sda1 for "/" or root partition ...

Then do it while the partition is not "live". You can run the necessary programs using a 'Live CD/USB', and it'll treat your main OS as just another ordinary partition.

To encrypt an existing partition and avoid losing data, you can use `luksipc`. (I've also heard that latest cryptsetup versions have this functionality built in to `cryptsetup-reencrypt`.) Do not 'format' the partition!

(Recommendation: First encrypt a *data* partition or two until you have a good grip on how cryptsetup, luksipc and related tools work.)